# Liquid does not print object.field property

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm new to `Liquid` and I'm trying to create a `Mechanic` script in `Shopify` to loop through all my orders and check each SKU. This is what I came up with:

```
{% for line_item in order.line_items %}
    {% if line_item.sku %}
        {{ line_item.sku }}
            {% capture sku %}
```

On the third line, I was expecting to see it print an order's SKU, which should look like this: `1xSAMPLE1+2xSAMPLE2`. It, however, showed me this error:

```
lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      1xS
                     (right here) ------^

Typically, this comes down to a stray comma, or some other character that makes for invalid JSON.

Context (lines 2-5 of rendered JSON):
```

As I understand it, `Mechanic` (or `Liquid`) only wants to print JSON values. How do I view my variables while running the `Mechanic` script?

Here is the full code and the error log:
[image]

Comment: I think you need to ask the same from APP support, they better able to answer it.

Comment: You open a capture statement, and then nest other capture statements inside it? Did you invent that script or is that copy and paste from some source? Seems really corrupt if you ask me.

Comment: @DavidLazar I misunderstood what capture meant. I thought it was supposed to catch the result of the execution directly above it. I got it working with assign

Comment: Yes. All good. You did well to figure that out.